# Moving a small aircraft over grass in winter

Tags: automotive-engineering, transportation

I really hope i am in the right place for this question. In a flight club we have an aircraft that weighs about 480kg. On the ground it taxis (drives) on three small wheels while only two of them are really carrying most of the weight.

In fall and winter the surface (grass) of our airfeeld often gets to wet so if we would move the aircraft we would damage the field and we get insulted by the older people in the club.

Preparing the airfield itsself is not possible because of environmental reasons and because we only rented the field and because the distance we need to travel is about 1km many of the options regarding the airfield are out.

I was now thinking of a trailer, with bigger wheels or even tracked vehicle or some kind of remote controlled vehicle that we can load the aircraft on and then pull that trailer to the runway. (The runway itsself is in pretty good shape the whole year).

We have people of many professions in the club so we are able to build stuff.

The question is, does anyone have an idea on how to solve this problem? Are there any existing solutions? How to spread the weight of that aircraft so that we will not damage the field still beeing able to pull it by hand.

Any thoughts?

Here is a picture of that aircraft:

https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/8664499

Also a rudimentary sketch (the correct side view is the right one, the left one shows a different version of the aircraft):

[image]

Comment: Ask on Aviaton SE. They actually fly their own planes over there.

Answer (score 1):

So having moved lots of agricultural equipment for a contractor on many farms in all conditions.

I would suggest a tractor with large low ground pressure tires and a trailer with the same large lgp tires.

Then consider having two people, for each wing end to stop it tipping or rocking too much.

Comment: Thanks so far, a tractor is actually already in place for mowing so that could be a good starting point. Wow sometimes all you need is a keyword "low ground pressure" brings up lots of useful results.